# Can I restrict which user can use a given term of taxonomy?

Tags: users, taxonomy-terms

I am using Taxonomy as Category.

For example taxonomy "Categories" have "Internal Coms" as term.

Then I have a view that shows all Internal Coms.

But this term must be used only by some users (or role), because those are institutional communications.

I see that any user that can publish an article can select Internal Coms. as term and then his post will be shown as something that it is not.

How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Taxonomy Term Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_permissions) seems to be created just for this purpose:

> This module allows taxonomy administrators the ability to restrict setting individual terms on nodes by user or role.

Alternatively, you could implement `mymodule_form_alter()`. In it, test something like `user_access('use_internals')`, and if it returns `false`, remove forbidden terms from `[#options]`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289211/2389310

Comment: Yes I saw it but it is not maintained any more and has many critical bugs :(

Comment: It claims to be maintained, but I admit it's a long time since I was trying it.

Comment: I just created a new Content Type to use core permissions.